# OpenGL Game Engine Renderer

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering

I'm developing a rendering engine using OpenGL and I'm wanting to know:

Should duplicated vertices (for flat shading, we need to duplicate vertices as we have 2+ normals for a single vertex) be created in the model or should an algorithm be implemented in the engine to work out when vertices need to be duplicated. An example would be a model of a rock which has sharp edges and smooth surfaces.

It makes sense to me that the artist would duplicate vertices for sharp edges in the modelling software as the engine has no idea what the artist's intentions are (in regards to model features). The engine **could** identify which vertices should be duplicated by checking the angle between face normals but to me, doing this could overwrite features of the model.

This is specifically for .obj models as different exporters may (? haven't looked into it) provide options to cater for this need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be defining the duplicate vertices yourself, insofar as they're not *really* duplicate vertices.

In Graphics Programming terms, a "vertex" is supposed to define *all* the necessary information to define a single point. This includes, but is not necessarily limited to: Position, Normal, Texture Coordinates, and Untextured Colors.

So in general, a Vertex is only "duplicate" if *all* of this defined data is identical (plus or minus Epsilon) when comparing two points. If you write an algorithm to detect and remove such duplicates, I'd say there's no problem.

Where you'll get a problem is when you're expecting an algorithm to accurately decide if a vertex should be "smooth" or "flat" because no one algorithm will ever get it right. Especially in your case: if you expect the rock to *always* be smooth shaded (which is reasonable for any particularly worn rock) you'd probably be okay, but given that you need it to consider both smooth and sharp edges, your algorithm will always screw it up. You'll need both situations where a < `10° angle` is shaded smoothly, and a > `170° angle` is shaded flatly. You won't get it right unless the model itself provides those rules.

So, to sum up: Just create the duplicate vertices in the model. Don't try to algorithm your way out of it. Most decent 3d modelling programs should provide features which will make this process relatively painless.